# Working C# code for the Windows clipboard?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, api, gdi

How do I convert the following C++ code (for taking a Bitmap from the Clipboard and copy it onto a form), into a WPF C# code that also uses APIs (not inbuilt Clipboard helpers from the .NET Framework) to copy it into a BitmapSource (or Bitmap for that matter)?

```
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); 
if (hdcMem != NULL) 
{ 
    if (OpenClipboard(hwnd)) 
    { 
        hbm = (HBITMAP) 
            GetClipboardData(uFormat); 
        SelectObject(hdcMem, hbm); 
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc); 

        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, 
            hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); 
        CloseClipboard(); 
    } 
    DeleteDC(hdcMem); 
}
```

My implementation **in WPF C# code** is as follows. Probably awfully wrong. The thing is that I am getting a black image out of it.

```
IntPtr hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
IntPtr hdcMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 64, 64);
if (hdcMem != null)
{
    if (OpenClipboard(MainWindow.Handle))
    {
        IntPtr hbm = GetClipboardData((uint)clipboardFormat);
        SelectObject(hdcMem, hbm);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 64, 64, hdcMem, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the original code? That is where your mistakes are. For instance in your version hdcMem is named as if you think it is a display context, and it's used as if it is a display context (in SelectObject) but it isn't, it's a  bitmap.

Comment: Well the original code copies from the clipboard to the screen. I want to copy from the clipboard to a bitmap. You got my problem all right. Can you help me solve it?

Comment: Something like this `IntPtr hDstdc = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero); IntPtr hDstBm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDstdc, 64, 64); SelectObject(hDstdc, hDstBm); IntPtr hSrcdc = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero); ... IntPtr hDstbm = GetClipboardData((uint)clipboardFormat); SelectObject(hDstDc, hDstbm); BitBlt(hDstdc, 0, 0, 64, 64, hSrcdc, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY)`. You have to create two display contexts, then you create the destination bitmap and get the source bitmap from the clipboard, then you select each bitmap into a display context, and then you call BitBlt.

Comment: But really it's a long time since I've done this stuff, I'm not making any promises.

Comment: That worked. Post it as a solution, and I'll give you credits, like you deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
IntPtr hDstdc = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
IntPtr hDstBm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDstdc, 64, 64);
SelectObject(hDstdc, hDstBm);
IntPtr hSrcdc = CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
...
IntPtr hSrcbm = GetClipboardData((uint)clipboardFormat);
SelectObject(hSrcDc, hSrcbm);
BitBlt(hDstdc, 0, 0, 64, 64, hSrcdc, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY).
```

You have to create two display contexts, then you create the destination bitmap and get the source bitmap from the clipboard, then you select each bitmap into a display context, and then you call BitBlt.

But really it's a long time since I've done this stuff, I'm not making any promises.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a custom implementation to workaround the bug in `Clipboard.GetImage`, you can find it [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/).

Comment: That's cool, and thumbs up for that. But I want to write it using APIs entirely, also to improve my knowledge on how APIs generally work.